# What's this boolean law called

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, first-order-logic

I think it is always true that

```
x || (x && y)
```

is equivalent to

```
x
```

If so, what is that law called?  I'm not even sure how I would Google for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a [*Redundancy Law*](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#redundancelaw).

```
A + A·B = A
```